# How do you get the total number of cores on the GPU

Tags: c#, gpgpu

Is there any way to get the system's GPU information in a .Net application?  I am writing a GPGPU application and would like to know what the total number of cores in the system’s graphics card.  I need to know this so I can dynamically alter how I’m processing the data through the GPU.

Comment: What framework do you use (OpenCL, CUDA etc.)? Each one has an API for querying device information

Comment: Also the definition of "core" [is not strictly defined](http://superuser.com/questions/705654/is-it-possible-to-have-two-cores-in-one-gpu/705657#705657), can you elaborate on exactly what you want to count when you say "core"?

Comment: I’m not using OpenCL or CUDA.  I’m running computations into HLSL shader code using XNA.  When I say core I’m talking about streamprocessors.

Answer (score 1):

You may get this information with CUDA.

The device properties provided by cuda API with the call to [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0) will help you get the total number of multiprocessors. Depending on compute capability you may then get the number of cores per multiprocessor. The deviceQuery SDK sample may guide you to this.

The method is available in the `cudart_{arch}_{ver}.dll`. Here is an example of P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport(CUDARTDLL, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "cudaGetDeviceProperties")]
public static extern cudaError_t cudaGetDeviceProperties(out cudaDeviceProp props, int device);
```

This requires the deployment of the cuda runtime dll though.

CUDA cores perform the vertex and fragment graphics operations, hence could be (used to be) named streamprocessors.

Answer (score -2):

This may been of use to you. [Here.](http://gpgpu.org/2011/07/29/gpu-net-2-released)